# Custom TableView Cell is not Clickable

Tags: swift, tableview

I have created a custom tableview cell by creating a separate class for it. The code works fine with the only exception being that if I tap the label in the cell, the cell does not register that it was selected. However, when the image in the cell is tapped, the cell registers it perfectly fine. I have included the cell's class's implementation below. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

```
class ItemCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    var message: String?
    var itemImage: UIImage?

    var messageView: UITextView = {
        var text = UITextView()
        return text
    }()

    var itemImageView: UIImageView = {
        var itemImage = UIImageView()
        return itemImage
    }()
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.addSubview(messageView)
        self.addSubview(itemImageView)

        itemImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        itemImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        itemImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        itemImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        itemImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

        messageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        messageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.itemImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
        messageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        messageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        let fixedWidth = messageView.frame.size.width - 50
        let newSize = messageView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        messageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: newSize.height).isActive = true
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if let message = message {
            messageView.text = message
            messageView.font = UIFont(name: messageView.font!.fontName, size: 15)
            messageView.isEditable = false
            messageView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }
        if let image = itemImage {
            itemImageView.image = image
        }
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `UIextView` for your label and not `UILabel` your text view catches taps earlier than the cell. Set `messageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` to avoid this behaviour.